# Attempting to search a pandas data frame column using a list

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to search a pandas data frame column using a two separate lists I have created.  The column I am attempting to search has a complex format and contains both Latitude and Longitude values.  My goal is to filter out only the Locations that are in my lat_long.xlsx file.  Here is a sample of column I am trying to search
[013077197:51082:-72.452118:41.853474:250:-1.0:]

I am trying to search this column with a list of latitude and longitudes in this format

Latitude Longitude
41.853   -72.452

I basically planned to convert my sample column to a string and then search using latitude create a new data frame then searching the new data frame for Longitude. I have no idea how I can search a column using a list of values imported.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  This is all I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('ReportAU_3411209.xlsx', index_col=False)

df_tower_locations = pd.read_csv('Milford2.csv')
Longitude = df_tower_locations['Longitude'].tolist()
Latitude = df_tower_locations['Latitude'].tolist()
```

Comment: Your example is unclear. For example, you mention a "lat_long.xlsx", but you show a different xlsx file. You should also show a brief part (e.g., the header) of the dataframe or just the relevant column. And does the column contain a string with brackets at start and end?

Comment: write a desired output, It's not clear what you need

Comment: If the cells in the relevant column are formatted like "[013077197:51082:-72.452118:41.853474:250:-1.0:]" strings, you could probably use `df['relevant-column'] = df['relevant-column'].str.split(':'); df = df.explode(column='relevant-column')`. You then have the relevant info in separate columns, which is easier to work with. Though you may want to convert some values to float afterwards.

Comment: Do you require matching *exact* values, or within a certain accuracy? For exact values, you'll probably want latitude and longitude to be strings, while for with a certain accuracy, you'll want floating point comparisons.

Comment: My goal is to create a new excel that only contains lat long values from the list I created.  I want to keep the same formatting of the CellLocation column because software we use rely on it being in this unusual format.  Here is a print out of my data frame that contains the "CellLocation' column: '            Item   ConnDateTime(UTC)  ...     MODEL                                      CellLocation
0               1 2021-06-11 04:45:30  ...  OGAY05-1  [013077197:51082:-72.452118:41.853474:250:-1.0:]

'

Comment: `Item   ConnDateTime(UTC)  ...     MODEL                                      CellLocation
0               1 2021-06-11 04:45:30  ...  OGAY05-1  [013077197:51082:-72.452118:41.853474:250:-1.0:]`

Comment: @9769953
It does not have to be an exact match.  The lists I created only has 3 decimal places. I basically want a value like 41.853 to be located in a value like 41.853474.